# Script for checking password strength

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that checks for the strength of a password. The code looks like this (with more more of those "blocks"):

```
if(passwordLC && lessThan12Password)
{
    $('.passwordStrenght').animate({width:'75px',height:'5px'},200).show();
    $('.passwordStrenght').css('background-color',red);
    $('#password').css('border-color',green);
    $('.passwordStrenghtInfo').text(weak).show();
    passwordErrors = true;
}else


if(passwordUC && lessThan12Password)
{
    $('.passwordStrenght').animate({width:'75px',height:'5px'},200).show();
    $('.passwordStrenght').css('background-color',red);
    $('#password').css('border-color',green);
    $('.passwordStrenghtInfo').text(weak).show();
    passwordErrors = true;
}else

if(passwordN && lessThan12Password)
{
    $('.passwordStrenght').animate({width:'75px',height:'5px'},200).show();
    $('.passwordStrenght').css('background-color',red);
    $('#password').css('border-color',green);
    $('.passwordStrenghtInfo').text(weak).show();
    passwordErrors = true;
}else
```

And it goes on and on...

Is there a way to reduce all that code to something simpler and efficient, or am I stuck with those horrible "blocks" of repeated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on your exact requirements and the context.
In your case, you could simplify the `if`-condition like below. If all fit into one `if`, you can write your code block there only once. If you need it and can't unify your condition, make it a function.

Here, I'm using a combined approach. I put the code from your `if` into a function, jQuery objects are cached and don't have to be recreated (but are still protected from outside modification because they only exist inside the scope of that function). And I combined all the conditions I could see in your example.

```
var indicateBadPassword = (function() {
        var $passwordStrength = $('.passwordStrength'),
            $password = $('#password'),
            $passwordStrengthInfo = $('.passwordStrenghtInfo');
        return function() {
            $passwordStrength.
                animate({width:'75px',height:'5px'},200).
                show().
                css('background-color',red);
            $password.css('border-color',green);
            $passwordStrengthInfo.text(weak).show();
            passwordErrors = true;

        }
    })();
if (lessThan12Password && (passwordLC || passwordUC || passwordN)) {
    indicateBadPassword();
}
```